# Flask {% extend "base.html" %}, but don't want the button in nav to display on form page

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

When I click on the button to go to the post job page I want the navigation to show by extending base.html, but I don't want the post job button to show on the page anymore beings I'm on the post job page. How would I do this?

I don't really want to use javascript window.onload to remove it.

any other ideas or how would I do this in flask?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}JustRemote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="logo" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"ß"><span class="logo-char">J</span>ust<span class="logo-char">R</span>emote</a>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Design</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Customer Service</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        {% block button %}
            <form class="post-job-form" action="{{ url_for('post_job') }}">
                <button class="post-job" type="submit">Post Job :)</button>
            </form>
        {% endblock %}
    </header>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, doing this on the Post Jobs page should work.

```
{% extend "base.html" %}

{% block button %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %} Hi! {% endblock %}
```

Comment: That worked for me! I tried it yesterday and it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'll accept your answer.